# Return JSON Response with form errors in Laravel

Tags: php, json, validation, laravel-5

So I currently validate my forms by doing:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title'    => 'required',
        'content'  => 'required|min:3'
    ]);
```

How do I take these validation errors and push them back through JSON? The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation) state that `$this->validate(...)` if false will redirect back and allow you to display errors ...

How do you validate server side for API requests?

Comment: Maybe with ```$validator->errors()``` ?
cf https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#working-with-error-messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **Validator::make** and then return response in json with array or your errors.

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Response::json(['errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()], 200);
    }
```

Note that you also need to setup **$rules** variable.
For example:

```
$rules = ['email' => 'required|email'];
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hint: since Laravel requires PHP 5.5 using `array()` instead of `[]` is quite pointless

Comment: I am saying that if you are using Laravel you must use PHP 5.5+ which includes short array syntax. So instead of `$rules = array('email' => 'required|email|');` just write `$rules = ['email' => 'required|email|'];` See: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: Oh I get it now! Thanks!